# setIconified(false) force closes my app

Tags: android, android-fragments, forceclose

Right now I have it not force closing but the keyboard pops up without the search box openning up, like in this picture:

[image]

My Search Fragment activity looks like:

```
public class Search extends Fragment implements SearchView.OnQueryTextListener, ReadJSONResult.OnArticleSelectedListener {

    private ListView lv;
    View v;
    SearchView searchView;
    private SearchView mSearchView;
    private MenuItem mSearchMenuItem;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        //set layout here
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_search, container, false);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
        getActivity().setTitle("Search");


        //get user information
        SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
        String userName = prefs.getString("userName", null);
        String userID = prefs.getString("userID", null);

        //ActionBar actionBar = getActivity().getActionBar();





        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return v;


}


    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu (Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.

        searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.menu_search2).getActionView();
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
        searchView.setIconified(false);
    }




    public boolean onQueryTextSubmit (String query) {

        //toast query

        //make json variables to fill

        // url to make request
        String url = "myURL";



        try {
            query = URLEncoder.encode(query, "UTF-8");
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        String jsonUrl = url + query;



        //todo: get json
        ReadJSONResult task = new ReadJSONResult(getActivity());
        task.setOnArticleSelectedListener(this);
        task.execute(jsonUrl);

        return false;
    }





    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onArticleSelected(String b, String brewery){

        //code to execute on click
        Fragment Fragment_one;
        FragmentManager man= getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction tran = man.beginTransaction();

        Fragment_one = new BeerPage();
        final Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("beerIDSent", b);
        bundle.putString("breweryIDSent", brewery);
        Fragment_one.setArguments(bundle);
        tran.replace(R.id.main, Fragment_one);//tran.
        tran.addToBackStack(null);
        tran.commit();

    }





}
```

my android action bar menu xml is:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <item android:id="@+id/menu_search2"
        android:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView"
        android:title="Search"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView"
        />
</menu>
```

The activity this fragment is loaded into is:

```
public class MainDrawer2 extends FragmentActivity
{
    private static final String EXTRA_NAV_ITEM    = "extraNavItem";
    private static final String STATE_CURRENT_NAV = "stateCurrentNav";

    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;

    private NavDrawerListAdapter mDrawerAdapter;
    private ListView mDrawerList;

    private CharSequence mTitle;
    private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;

    private MainNavItem mCurrentNavItem;


    public static Intent createLaunchFragmentIntent(Context context, MainNavItem navItem)
    {
        return new Intent(context, MainDrawer2.class)
                .putExtra(EXTRA_NAV_ITEM, navItem.ordinal());
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_main);

        mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();
        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout)findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mDrawerList   = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.drawer);

        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        enableHomeButtonIfRequired();

        mDrawerAdapter = new NavDrawerListAdapter(getApplicationContext());
        mDrawerList.setAdapter(mDrawerAdapter);
        mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new ListView.OnItemClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
            {
                displayNavFragment((MainNavItem)parent.getItemAtPosition(position));
            }
        });

        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
                R.drawable.ic_drawer, R.string.app_name, R.string.app_name)
        {
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view)
            {
                getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }

            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView)
            {
                getActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }
        };

        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

        if(getIntent().hasExtra(EXTRA_NAV_ITEM)){
            MainNavItem navItem = MainNavItem.values()
                    [getIntent().getIntExtra(EXTRA_NAV_ITEM,
                    MainNavItem.STATISTICS.ordinal())];
            displayNavFragment(navItem);
        }
        else if(savedInstanceState != null){
            mCurrentNavItem = MainNavItem.values()
                    [savedInstanceState.getInt(STATE_CURRENT_NAV)];
            setCurrentNavItem(mCurrentNavItem);
        }
        else{
            displayNavFragment(MainNavItem.STATISTICS);
        }
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH)
    private void enableHomeButtonIfRequired()
    {
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH){
            getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void setTitle(CharSequence title)
    {
        mTitle = title;
        getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig)
    {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        // Pass any configuration change to the drawer toggles
        mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState)
    {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putInt(STATE_CURRENT_NAV, mCurrentNavItem.ordinal());
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
    {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    /*
    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
    {
        // if nav drawer is opened, hide the action items
        boolean drawerOpen = mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList);
        menu.findItem(R.id.action_settings).setVisible(!drawerOpen);
        return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
    */

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
    {
        if(mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)){
            return true;
        }
        switch(item.getItemId()){
            case R.id.menu_search2:
                displayNavFragment(MainNavItem.SEARCH);
                return true;

            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    private void displayNavFragment(MainNavItem navItem)
    {
        if(navItem == mCurrentNavItem){
            return;
        }
        Fragment fragment = Fragment.instantiate(this,
                navItem.getFragClass().getName());
        if(fragment != null){
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.main, fragment)
                    .commit();
            setCurrentNavItem(navItem);
        }
    }

    private void setCurrentNavItem(MainNavItem navItem)
    {
        int position = navItem.ordinal();
        // If navItem is in DrawerAdapter
        if(position >= 0 && position < mDrawerAdapter.getCount()){
            mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
        }
        else{
            // navItem not in DrawerAdapter, de-select current item
            if(mCurrentNavItem != null){
                mDrawerList.setItemChecked(mCurrentNavItem.ordinal(), false);
            }
        }
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
        setTitle(navItem.getTitleResId());
        mCurrentNavItem = navItem;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is line 41 on `Search.java`?

Comment: searchView.setIconified(false);

Comment: You find out what the solution is yet?

Answer (score 1):

looks like here

```
searchView.setIconified(false);
```

"searchView" has not been initialized properly yet, because before you create the field, but didn't assign any view for it:

```
SearchView searchView;
```

So in your onCreateView you should find your View by Id first before calling methods of searchView:

```
searchView = (SearchView) findViewById(R.id.the_view_id_here);
```

Comment: then double check the id. Is it correct? Is it contained inside the layout that the Fragment inflated? ... in fact you commentted out the code that inflates the layout? Why?

Comment: I just added my xml code for my action bar to my above question. Could it be that its really not inflated till its returned at the end of the fragment?

Comment: ah.. it's in the actionbar menu I did overread that. then maybe try getting your searchView like this before calling .setIconified(false) : `searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.menu_search2).getActionView();` instead the findViewById

Comment: that has my keyboard opening, but the search box at the top is not opening.

Comment: Okey dokey, I updated my code above and added some more code. I am still stuck...